# Show that a convergent orthogonal sequence in a Hilbert space has limit zero

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $(x_n)$ be an orthogonal sequence in a Hilbert Space $H$, that is $\langle x_n,x_m\rangle =0$ when $n\neq m$. Show that, if $(x_n)$ converges, the limit must be $0$.

My ideas: Every convergent sequence is also a Cauchy sequence, and therefore the result follows, considering $\langle x_n-x_m,x_n-x_m\rangle = \langle x_n,x_n\rangle + \langle x_m,x_m\rangle - \langle x_m,x_n\rangle - \langle x_n,x_m\rangle$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof could be continued this way: for $n>m$ we have $$\|x_n-x_m\|^2=\|x_n\|^2+\|x_m\|^2\ge \|x_m\|^2$$ Therefore $\|x_m\|\to 0.$

Comment: +1. We use the fact that in any normed linear space, if $\|x_n-x\|\to 0.$ then $\|x_n\|\to\|x\|$ because $\|x\|-\|x-x_n\|\le \|x-(x-x_n)\|=\|x_n\|=\|(x_n-x)+x\|\le \|x_n-x\|+\|x\|.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for upvoting. I do not get your point. I have based on the Cauchy condition, not on the convergence.  If $m$ is large enough then $\|x_n-x_m\|$ is small, as $n>m.$

Comment: The point is $2\|x\|^2=\lim \|x_n\|^2+\|x_{n+1}\|^2=\lim \|x_n-x_{n+1}\|^2=0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ok. Now I see your point. However you do not need to introduce $x.$ If $\lim \|x_n\|^2 =0$ then $x_n\to 0.$

Comment: Agreed......................

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is unfinished. Suppose $x$ is the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and consider that
$$
0 = \langle x_n,x_m\rangle.
$$
First let $n\to\infty$ and then let $m\to\infty$ in the above expression. What do you get?